# I am getting an error that my createDrawerNavigator is not function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the below error when I am trying to import my `createDrawerNavigator` 
The expected output is that the splash page opens on the Login screen. The `appNavigator` code is below.

```
  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The error is below:

```
(0, _reactNavigation.DrawerNavigator) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNavigation.DrawerNavigator)({
    Splash: _splash.default
  }, RouteConfig)', '(0, _reactNavigation.DrawerNavigator)' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `v4` of `react-navigation` you have to install a package for `drawerNavigation`

> yarn add react-navigation-drawer

And use it :

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

createDrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig);
```

Full doc is [here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html)

Comment: If it solved your problem dont forget to accept the answer!